# Unit docker.socket not found

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, docker

Cannot run docker daemon, `sudo systemctl status docker.socket` returns `Loaded: Not found (Reason: No such file or directory)`.

I had modified docker.service, `sudo systemctl edit docker.service` and tried multiple things for ExecStart `/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://` and also `/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:unix//` but still I have the same issue.

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04.5

Any idea? Thx

Comment: Even more I cannot open for writing `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution was to remove docker from machine and re-install it.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge docker-ce
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
$ sudo rm -rf /etc/docker
$ sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
```